# Cannot resolve enum values by name in Xcode debugger

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, enums, lldb

With an enum typedef'd in a global header file used throughout my project, I am unable to refer to the individual enum values by name while using lldb in Xcode.

For example, if I am stopped at a breakpoint anywhere the enum type is available, and I try to evaluate something at the lldb prompt in Xcode (e.g. `(lldb) p (int)EnumConstant`), lldb complains:

```
error: use of undeclared identifier 'EnumConstant'
```

Furthermore, if I try to set a conditional breakpoint using an enum constant in the condition (e.g. right-click breakpoint in Xcode > Edit Breakpoint... > Condition: `EnumConstant == someLocalVar`), then Xcode complains every time it tries to evaluate that condition at that breakpoint:

```
Stopped due to an error evaluating condition of breakpoint 1.1: "EnumConstant == someLocalVar"
Couldn't parse conditional expression:
error: use of undeclared identifier 'EnumConstant'
```

Xcode's code completion popover even resolves a suggestion for the enum constant when I begin typing the name in the "Edit Breakpoint..." window, so Xcode itself doesn't have a problem resolving it.

Is there an option I can set in lldb or Xcode so that lldb maintains the enum identifiers *after* compilation? I'm assuming the enum constants get translated to their ordinal value during compilation, causing the executable to discard the identifiers, but thats just my naive speculation.

When I use the equivalent code in a simple GNU C program in Linux or Cygwin (minus the class definitions obviously), but using gcc/gdb instead of Xcode/lldb, I don't have these problems. It is able to resolve the enum values no problem.

---

I've created a tiny Xcode iPhone project to demonstrate what I mean. Using any of the `enum_t` constants below within the `ViewController.m` context (the for-loop is a good place to demo) will produce the same results.

ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

typedef enum
{
    eZero, eOne, eTwo, eCOUNT
}
enum_t;

extern NSString const * const ENUM_STR[];

@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

NSString const * const ENUM_STR[eCOUNT] = { @"eZero", @"eOne", @"eTwo" };

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    for (enum_t value = eZero; value < eCOUNT; ++value)
    {
        NSLog(@"%-8@ = %d", ENUM_STR[value], value);
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug (fairly longstanding) in how the name->Debug Information lookup-accelerator tables for enums are built.  While enum types are listed, enum values are not.  That was surely done to save output debug info size - debug information gets quite big pretty quickly, and so there's a constant tension between the cost of adding more info and the utility of that more info. So far this one hasn't risen to the level of inclusion.

Anyway, doing a search through "all debug information for anything with a name that matches 'eZero'" is prohibitively slow even for decent sized projects, and gets really bad for large ones.  So lldb always uses these name->Debug Info tables for its first level access.

Because the accelerator tables do contain the enum type by name (and more important for you typedefs by name as well), the workaround is to do:

(lldb) expr enum_t::eZero
(int) $0 = 0

Of course, if you have truly anonymous enums, then you are pretty much out of luck till this info gets added to the accelerator tables.

BTW, the Xcode symbol completion in the Debugger Console window is done using the Xcode SourceKit indexer, not lldb.  So the completions offered from Xcode are not a reflection of lldb's knowledge of the program.

BBTW, gdb doesn't use compiler-made accelerator tables (these were an Apple extension up till the new DWARF 5 standard) but manually builds an index by scanning the debug info.  That allows them to index whatever seems best to the debugger.  OTOH, it makes debugger startup quite a bit slower for big projects.